# Ensuring a python queue that can be populated by multiple threads will always be cleared without polling

Tags: python, python-3.x, queue, thread-safety, python-multithreading

I have the below code that shows how a queue would always be cleared even with multiple threads adding to the queue. It's using recursion but a while loop could work as well. Is this a bad practice or would there be a scenario where the queue might have an object and it won't get pulled until something gets added to the queue.

The primary purpose of this is to have a queue that ensures order of execution without the need to continually poll or block with q.get()

```
import queue
import threading
lock = threading.RLock()
q = queue.Queue()

def execute():
    with lock:
        if not q.empty():
            text = q.get()
            print(text)
            execute()


def add_to_queue(text):
    q.put(text)
    execute()

# Assume multiple threads can call add to queue
add_to_queue("Hello")
```

Comment: You don't need a lock on top of a concurrent queue, that lock is also blocking. Also I'm not sure why you need to clear the thread without blocking or polling, the queue is designed to block on get so that your consumer threads don't have to poll

Comment: Do you mean you want to ensure that the queue is empty before the thread exits?

Comment: @klanmiko Ok I should rephrase the blocking aspect. Yes what I mean is I want the queue to be empty before the thread exits without there being a chance for an object to be added and getting stuck after the thread exits.

Comment: @klanmiko So yes ensure the queue is empty before the thread exits

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one solution that uses timeout on the .get function, one pushes to the queue and one reads from the queue. You could have multiple readers and writers.

```
import queue
import threading
q = queue.Queue()

def read():
    try:
        while True:
            text = q.get(timeout=1)
            print(text)
    except queue.Empty:
        print("exiting")

def write():
    q.put("Hello")
    q.put("There")
    q.put("My")
    q.put("Friend")

writer = threading.Thread(target=write)
reader = threading.Thread(target=read)

writer.start()
reader.start()

reader.join()
```